# How to convert a unicode in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

There are two tables in my db: `InvoiceDetail` and `ProductDetail`. I want to write a search condition in which if I search for a product or a client, it will display the related invoice. Here is my code for `searchClickevent`.

It is giving an error `The query syntax is not valid. Near term '>', line 6, column 136.`

```
protected void SearchInvoiceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    String WhereClause = "it.UserID==@UserID AND it.IsDeleted == false AND (it.ClientDetail.ClientName LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%') OR (it.InvoiceDetail.Any(p=>p.ItemName))";
    EntityDataSourceInvoice.Where = WhereClause;
    ViewState["InvoiceViewWhereClause"] = WhereClause;

    if (EntityDataSourceInvoice.WhereParameters["SearchTerm"] != null)
    {

        EntityDataSourceInvoice.WhereParameters["SearchTerm"].DefaultValue = SafeSearchLiteral(SearchTextBox.Text.Trim());
    }

    else
    {
        Parameter CategoryParameter = new Parameter("SearchTerm", System.Data.DbType.String, SafeSearchLiteral(SearchTextBox.Text.Trim()));
        CategoryParameter.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
        EntityDataSourceInvoice.WhereParameters.Add(CategoryParameter);
    }        
    InvoiceGrid.DataBind();
    InvoiceGrid.AllowPaging = false;
    InvoiceGrid.AllowPaging = true;
}
```

Comment: `t.InvoiceDetail.Any(p=>p.ItemName)` is not valid SQL. Which database are you running this against?

Comment: You can't use LINQ inside the SQL where clause. The same thing applies to the `it.UserID==@UserID` - that's C#, not SQL. I think you are confusing LINQ and SQL... Why are you using custom SQL anyway? It doesn't seem that there's any reason to do so.

Comment: pretty sure this has exactly nothing to do with "unicode"; did you mean to say "lambda"?

Comment: Looks like you are using a [LinqDataSource](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/linqdatasource-control-in-Asp-Net-3-5/) control. Have a look at the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.where(v=vs.110).aspx) property syntax and at this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

I don't know class/table/EntityDatasource structure but i guess this should work, Change is only is whereclause:-

```
String WhereClause = "it.UserID==@UserID AND it.IsDeleted == false 
AND ((it.ClientDetail.ClientName LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%') 
OR (it.ItemName LIKE '%'+ @SearchTerm + '%'))";
```

Comment: You should explain what you have done here. At first glance the code looks like a copy and paste from the OP's question. You could have just copied the WhereClause variable instead of the whole code.

Comment: its giving error "'InvoiceDetail' is not a member of type 'OnlineInvoiceModel.InvoiceDetail' in the currently loaded schemas. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 117."

Comment: 'ItemName' is not a member of type 'OnlineInvoiceModel.InvoiceDetail' in the currently loaded schemas. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 117.